Color usage percentage in illustrator or photoshop
Is there a way to know the color usage in design through Adobe illustrator or Adobe photoshop?

Do you expect full statistics or only a way to check what percentage of the image area is covered by one given exact color? Should the given color have some tolerance range? To increase the possibility of an useful answer it's better to show an example image and specify with it what you actually want.

Hi. Do you mean ink coverage?  If so, You could save as a PDF and inspect the Output Preview in Adobe Acrobat see how here
